# Filtering a list with given condition

Tags: c#-4.0

Given the list `var items = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-10 };` what is the best way ensure whether all the entries inside the list are positive numbers?

Normally i set a flag like this

```
foreach(int i in items)
{
   if( i < 0) ... update the flagVariable

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool allPositive = items.All(i => i > 0);
```

although given your condition, you might actually be checking there are no negative values:

```
bool noNegatives = items.All(i => i >= 0);
```

[`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) is an extension method defined in the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class, so to use it you need to a add a reference to the System.Core assembly and add a

`using System.Linq;` directive to the top of your file.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this requires `Linq`

Answer (score 0):

Check this post [List.TrueForAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The following code does the trick

```
var isPositiveEntries = items.TrueForAll(number => number > 0);
```